# Translation of the same activity uses two different string resource files

Tags: android, user-interface, language-translation

I have an activity that needs to be translated into different languages. The translations have been added and applied to the activity. Most of the activity get translated from the correct string resource, however some elements keep using the default string resource.

I have tested those particular elements by changing the values in different files and it works as described above - one part keeps default resource, the other one uses the correct translated resource.

Nowhere in code text is being set in anyway, the only thing that I do with those elements is setting visibility.

Strings are set as translatable.

I have no idea where to even start, but I presume this has to be a bug in Android SDK. Any idea what to do here?

Comment: Post resources that are not get translated. I think you changed their attributes to `translatable = false` in default string resource.

Comment: Not true. This is an example of a string that is not getting translated:
    ```<string name="events">EVENTS</string>```